# Triangulation of a Convex Polygon

Tags: computational-geometry, triangulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explanation/Intuition behind why $C_n$ counts the number of triangulations of a convex $n+2$-gon?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20806/explanation-intuition-behind-why-c-n-counts-the-number-of-triangulations-of-a)

I am interested in counting of how many distinct triangulation are there of a convex polygon of n vertices.

Of course it should be a function of n.

If you have a link to appropriate preferably simple paper, I'll appreciate sharing it with us.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to have a look at this question: [Explanation/Intuition behind why $C_n$ counts the number of triangulations of a convex $n+2$-gon?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20806/explanation-intuition-behind-why-c-n-counts-the-number-of-triangulations-of-a)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thank you very much!!!

Comment: If you work with larger figures at some time, SAGE (www.sagemath.org) has packages for counting triangulations of convex configurations in n-space.